# Filestream Progressbar report

Tags: c#

Could someone tell me or suggest how I can make the progressbar work with my current codes?
I'm decrypting files from directory. I want to show the progress.
I tried reporting the inputFiles count but I can't make it work.

Here's my code:

```
  private async Task Start()
    {
        int bufferSize = Convert.ToInt32(cbBufferSize.Text);
        int count = 0;

        foreach (ListViewItem lvi in LV.Items)
        {
            string inputhPaths = lvi.SubItems[0].Text;
            string keyPaths = lvi.SubItems[1].Text;
            outputPaths = Path.Combine(lvi.SubItems[2].Text, lvi.SubItems[3].Text + ".ts");

            using (var fsOutput = new FileStream(outputPaths, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                foreach (string inputFiles in Directory.GetFiles(inputhPaths, "*.ts"))
                {
                    using (var fsInput = new FileStream(inputFiles, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        count++;
                        progressBar1.Value = (int)count / inputFiles.Count() * 100;

                        await Task.Run(() => Decrypter.BufferMethod(fsInput, keyPaths, fsOutput, bufferSize));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: 'Can't make it work' isn't often a good enough description of your problem. What exactly happens when you run this?

Comment: duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57432133/how-to-report-progress-from-filestream

Comment: Sorry. I'm getting 200% progress and it's always throwing an error

Comment: I tried your suggested link but still not working for me

Comment: Alright I  tried this and it worked. 
counter += 1; progressBar1.Value = (int)(counter / (double)inputFiles.Count() * 100);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did like this and it worked

int counter = 0;
string inputFiles = ...............

```
counter += 1; 
progressBar1.Value = (int)(counter / (double)inputFiles.Count() * 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I approach this is to have my **DoWork** task method report progress and in my **ProgressChanged** method that handles progress updates, that's where I update my progressBar value.

Comment: Yeah I can do it in backgroundworker. 
But I'm moving now to async/await 
that's why I'm still learning how to use it properly