# How to calculate the progress of hashing System.IO.Hashing?

Tags: c#, hash

I want to move from the unofficial implementations of hash functions to the official [System.IO.Hashing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.hashing?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0). But I absolutely do not understand how to make a report on the progress of hashing? I intend to use the XxHash3 algorithm, but I think it doesn’t matter.

At the moment, I calculate the hash like this (without displaying progress):

```
private string GetXxHash3(string filename)
{
    var hashAlgorithm = new XxHash3();
    using (Stream entryStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filename))
        hashAlgorithm.Append(entryStream);
    return BitConverter.ToString(hashAlgorithm.GetHashAndReset()).Replace("-", string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to report progress on? `xxhash` is supposed to be "real time" so are you just asking how to use a [`stopwatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-7.0)?

Comment: @BurnsBA, Calculation of the hash of a large file does not occur in real time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to report progress from FileStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57432133/how-to-report-progress-from-filestream)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
string GetXxHash3(string filename, IProgress<long> progress)
{
    var hashAlgorithm = new XxHash3();
    using (Stream entryStream = File.OpenRead(filename))
    {
        byte[] buffer = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(4096); // use whatever chunk size you want
        int bytesRead;
        long totalRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = entryStream.Read(buffer)) > 0)
        {
            hashAlgorithm.Append(buffer.AsSpan(0, bytesRead));
            totalRead += bytesRead;
            progress.Report(totalRead);
        }
        ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(buffer);
    }
    return Convert.ToHexString(hashAlgorithm.GetHashAndReset());
}
```

(c) stephentoub

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest instead of appending the whole stream to the hashAlgorithm, step over it in chunks and then you can report on the progress of those chunks.

```
private string GetXxHash3(string filename)

{

    var hashAlgorithm = new XxHash3();
    var buffer = new Span<byte>(new byte[512]);
    using (Stream entryStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filename)) {
           while (entryStream.Read(buffer) > 0) {
               hashAlgorithm.Append(buffer);
               // report on progress based on entryStream.Position and the file's total length
            }
    }

    return BitConverter.ToString(hashAlgorithm.GetHashAndReset()).Replace("-", string.Empty);

}
```

Comment: In this case, an incorrect hash is obtained.

Comment: Ah yes, you need to make sure you don't send the whole buffer when you only read a subsection.