# HttpClient, implement progress when uploading File

Tags: c#, file, file-upload, uwp, dotnet-httpclient

I'm working on a UWP app that uploads files to a server using a custom API method. The file upload itself is functional, but I'm having trouble implementing progress tracking during the upload. I've tried several approaches, including creating a custom ProgressStreamContent class, but none seem to work

Here's the original API method without progress tracking:

```
public async Task<ApiResult<FileUploadResult>> UploadFile(string metadata, Stream content, string sessionId, string treeId, string nodeId,Action<long, long> progressCallback = null, CancellationToken? cancellationToken = null)
        {
            string url = $"{_httpHelper.GetFileUploadsBaseUrl()}/{sessionId}/{treeId}/{nodeId}";

            MultipartFormDataContent multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent
            {
                { new StringContent(metadata), "metadata" },
                { new StreamContent(content), "content" }

            };

            ApiResult<FileUploadResult> result = await _httpHelper.PostAsync<FileUploadResult>(url, multipartContent, cancellationToken);

            return result;

        }
```

And here's my attempt to add progress tracking using a custom ProgressStreamContent class:

```
    public class ProgressStreamContent : HttpContent
    {


        private const int defaultBufferSize = 5 * 4096;

        private HttpContent content;
        private int bufferSize;
        //private bool contentConsumed;
        private Action<long, long> progress;

        public ProgressStreamContent(HttpContent content, Action<long, long> progress) : this(content, defaultBufferSize, progress) { }

        public ProgressStreamContent(HttpContent content, int bufferSize, Action<long, long> progress)
        {
            if (content == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("content");
            }
            if (bufferSize <= 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("bufferSize");
            }

            this.content = content;
            this.bufferSize = bufferSize;
            this.progress = progress;

            foreach (var h in content.Headers)
            {
                this.Headers.Add(h.Key, h.Value);
            }
        }

        protected override Task SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
        {

            return Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var buffer = new Byte[this.bufferSize];
                long size;
                TryComputeLength(out size);
                var uploaded = 0;


                using (var sinput = await content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        var length = sinput.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        if (length <= 0) break;

         
                        uploaded += length;
                        progress?.Invoke(uploaded, size);

                        stream.Write(buffer, 0, length);
                        stream.Flush();
                    }
                }
                stream.Flush();
            });
        }

        protected override bool TryComputeLength(out long length)
        {
            length = content.Headers.ContentLength.GetValueOrDefault();
            return true;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                content.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
}
```

and here How I used it, I created DelegatingHandler to handle the progress

```
 public class ProgressMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        private Action<long, long> _onUploadProgress;

        public event Action<long, long> HttpProgress
        {
            add => _onUploadProgress += value;
            remove => _onUploadProgress -= value;
        }
        public ProgressMessageHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler) : base(innerHandler)
        {
        }
        protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var progressContent = new ProgressStreamContent(
                request.Content,
                4096,
                (sent, total) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Uploading {0}/{1}", sent, total);
                    OnUploadProgress(sent, total);
                });
            request.Content = progressContent;
            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
        private void OnUploadProgress(long bytesTransferred, long totalBytes)
        {
            _onUploadProgress?.Invoke(bytesTransferred, totalBytes);
        }
    }
```

and update the Api function to be like this

```
        public async Task<ApiResult<FileUploadResult>> UploadFile(string metadata, Stream content, string sessionId, string treeId, string nodeId,Action<long, long> progressCallback = null, CancellationToken? cancellationToken = null)
        {
            string url = $"{_httpHelper.GetFileUploadsBaseUrl()}/{sessionId}/{treeId}/{nodeId}";

            MultipartFormDataContent multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent
            {
                { new StringContent(metadata), "metadata" },
                { new ProgressStreamContent(new StreamContent(content), progressCallback), "content" }

            };

            ApiResult<FileUploadResult> result = await _httpHelper.PostAsync<FileUploadResult>(url, multipartContent, cancellationToken);

            return result;

        }
```

I'm seeking guidance on how to correctly implement progress tracking during the file upload process in my UWP app. Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are over-engineering this. You can use the `ProgressStream` [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57439154/14868997), then simply add an event handler to that.

I've modified this to add the necessary `async` versions.

```cs
public class ProgressStream : Stream
{
    private Stream _input;
    private long _progress;

    public event Action<long, long>? UpdateProgress;

    public ProgressStream(Stream input)
    {
        _input = input;
    }

    public override void Flush() => _input.Flush();

    public override Task FlushAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) => _input.FlushAsync(cancellationToken);

    public override int Read(Span<byte> buffer)
    {
        int n = _input.Read(buffer, offset, count);
        _progress += n;
        UpdateProgress?.Invoke(_progress, _input.Length);
        return n;
    }

    public override async ValueTask<int> ReadAsync(Memory<byte> buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        int n = await _input.ReadAsync(buffer, cancellationToken);
        _progress += n;
        UpdateProgress?.Invoke(_progress, _input.Length);
        return n;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) => _input.Dispose();

    public override ValueTask DisposeAsync() => _input.DisposeAsync();

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) => throw new System.NotImplementedException();

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) => throw new System.NotImplementedException();

    public override void SetLength(long value) => throw new System.NotImplementedException();

    public override bool CanRead => true;
    public override bool CanSeek => false;
    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override long Length => _input.Length;
    public override long Position
    {
        get {  return _input.Position; }
        set {  throw new System.NotImplementedException();}
    }
}
```

Then you connect the event handler and just use a normal `StreamContent`.

```
public async Task<ApiResult<FileUploadResult>> UploadFile(
  string metadata, Stream content, string sessionId, string treeId, string nodeId,
  Action<long, long> progressCallback = null, CancellationToken? cancellationToken = null)
{
    var url = $"{_httpHelper.GetFileUploadsBaseUrl()}/{sessionId}/{treeId}/{nodeId}";

    using var progressStream = progressCallback != null ? new ProgressStream(content) : content;
    // for performance use original stream if no callback
    if (progressCallback != null)
        progressStream.UpdateProgress += progressCallback;

    using var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent
    {
        { new StringContent(metadata), "metadata" },
        { new StreamContent(progressStream), "content" },
    };

    var result = await _httpHelper.PostAsync<FileUploadResult>(url, multipartContent, cancellationToken);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Big thanks! You really came to my rescue. With just a few tweaks for the .NET version, it worked like pure magic. Your help means a lot!

Comment: sorry, but the progress indicator hits 100% as soon as I initiate the file upload, even though the file isn't making it to the server. Any chance you could help me with this?

Comment: Maybe your progress calculation isn't correct? Log the values being sent to the event handler and see if they make sense.

Comment: Yes, I've logged the values, and they reach 100% immediately

Comment: So what values are you getting?

Comment: It is like this , but it reach to 100% in 1 second

`
Progress is 21.09%
Progress is 26.3625%
Progress is 31.635%
Progress is 36.9075%
Progress is 42.18%
Progress is 47.4525%
Progress is 52.72501%
Progress is 57.99751%
Progress is 63.27001%
Progress is 68.5425%
Progress is 73.815%
Progress is 79.08751%
Progress is 84.36001%
Progress is 89.63251%
Progress is 94.90501%
Progress is 100%
Progress is 100%
`

Comment: No the actual values being passed, the two `long` values. The first is bytes copied, the second is the total. Also how do you know it's not actually completed in that time?