# PortableDeviceApiLib show progress TransferContentToDevice()

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, wpd

I am using https://www.nuget.org/packages/PortableDevices/ to copy files to WPD.

I can copy files using `TransferContentToDevice(___,___)` function.

Right now, it's not showing any progress dialog. How can I show transfer progress?

**My Code**

```
            //Connect to MTP devices and pick up the first one
            var devices = new PortableDeviceCollection();
            devices.Refresh();

            if (devices.Count > 0)
            {
                device = devices.First();
                device.Connect();

                string rootId = device.GetRootId();
                device.TransferContentToDevice(@"C:\\test\testFile.mp4", rootId);

                //Close the connection
                device.Disconnect();
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine("No device connectd");
            }
```

**TransferContentToDevice() Function - From Portable Device API**

```
public void TransferContentToDevice(string fileName, string parentObjectId)
        {
            IPortableDeviceContent content;
            PortableDeviceClass.Content(out content);

            var values = GetRequiredPropertiesForContentType(fileName, parentObjectId);

            uint optimalTransferSizeBytes = 0;
            content.CreateObjectWithPropertiesAndData(values, out PortableDeviceApiLib.IStream tempStream, ref optimalTransferSizeBytes, null);

            var targetStream = (System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream)tempStream;

            try
            {
                using (var sourceStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    var buffer = new byte[optimalTransferSizeBytes];
                    int bytesRead;
                    do
                    {
                        bytesRead = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)optimalTransferSizeBytes);
                        var pcbWritten = IntPtr.Zero;
                        targetStream.Write(buffer, bytesRead, pcbWritten);
                    } while (bytesRead > 0);
                }
                targetStream.Commit(0);
            }
            finally
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(tempStream);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my search, it seems that we may not find a way to show the progress.

Because we don't how the PortableDevice transfer, like we don't know its Transmission rate,

and maximum and minimum.

You could look at 
 [File Copy with Progress Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044629/file-copy-with-progress-bar]) to know to how to set the progress bar when copying a file.

Comment: Actually, I have `TransferContentToDevice()` function code. See my edited answer.